# MySQL set Flag on first occurence of a value in another Field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following recordset (is_unique is empty):

```
+-----+----------+-------------+
| id  | is_unique| val         |
+-----+----------+-------------+
| 1   | 1        | 100100      |
| 2   | 1        | 222111      |
| 3   | 0        | 100100      |
| 4   | 0        | 222111      |
| 5   | 1        | 311111      |
+-----+----------+-------------+
```

How I can set is_unique = true for every first occur (regarding id) of the value in val?

Comment: edit and put your wished result please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a user variable:-

```
SET @prev:=0;

UPDATE someTable
SET is_unique=IF(@prev=val, 0, IF(@prev:=val, 1, 0 ))
ORDER BY val, id;
```

This sets the user variable to 0 (I am assuming val is an integer field). Then does the update, ordered by val and id. If @prev is the same as val then it sets is_unique to 0, otherwise it sets it to the result of checking the assignment of the current value of val to @prev.

SQL fiddle:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f9d50/1

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not too difficult to achieve. What you will need to do is have a subselect in your select statement to check if there are any other entries in the table with the same value and a lesser id. If such entry exists, we want to set is_unique to 0. Otherwise, is_unique should be set to 1.

```
Select Coalesce((
                Select top 1 0 
                From tabletest t2
                Where t2.val = t1.val
                and t2.id<t1.id), 1) as is_unique
From tabletest t1
```

Coalesce is a keyword in mysql that checks to see if the first value is null. If the value is not null, coalesce will use that value. If the value is null, the second input value will be used. So, if there is an entry in your table that has a smaller id than the current row, the subquery will pull back 0 and the coalesce will pass that 0 to the select. If the current record has the smallest id for that record, the subselect will be null and the coalesce will send 1 back to the select.